Possible reasons concerning decreased suspension height of an copper object in an electric field
I am transcribing an article that discusses electrostatic levitation. A segment of this article pertains to the author describing a charged spherical object composed of copper with its suspending position (or height) decreased when it accumulates heat from being in an electric field supplied by a positively charged sphere. He removes the object to let the heat dissipate and positions it back into the field, returning to its non-thermal position. What are the contributing factors that result in the sudden loss of height? I have my proposals, but I would be pleased to hear your responses. Thank you.

Which article...?
